# How to redirect user to a third-party site?

Tags: login, web, redirect

Context

A) https://**appname**.co

- This is the main login URL for our product

B) https://abcbusiness.**appname**.co

- We also sell our product to other business with a different URL. We add the business and our app name together for the new URL.

However, there are cases where user of B ended up at A login page. This maybe due to the search result since URL B contains the same keyword as A. Both also have the same interface. Only the URL and business logo are different.

Currently, when the user tried login in A using their credentials, the system will detect they are the users of B. We will then prompt a banner with the link at B so user can click and re-direct themselves to the right login URL.

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: `is_user_logged_in=true` . Then smoothly 301 redirect, they won't need to see another page at another subdomain. What happens in Vegas stays in Vegas. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Since you can detect the users business url, it should be possible to provide some sort of SSO (single sign on). This allows your users to log in in the main url and get redirected to the business url. If that is technically not possible, your proposed solution looks about right. But having to log in twice is not very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tell from the credentials that the user “should have” logged in at B instead of A (or *vice versa*), then the best solution from a UI/UX point of view is to put up a message saying “Redirecting your login to B/A” and then do so after a short delay, long enough for them to read the message. Ideally, you don’t even require them to re-enter their credentials, just log them right in to the correct site. However, you may have security requirements that I’m not aware of which militate against doing this. If you are redirecting without keeping the credentials (i.e., you are requiring them to re-enter their credentials), you might want to include a message on the target login page reminding them to bookmark *that* page rather than the other.